# Calculating the normal plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I'm given a function $f$ such that $$f(x,y,z):= x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6$$ I know that in order to find the equation of the plane tangent to this curve at the point $(1,-1,1,)$ I just find the derivative of $f$ at this point, which turns out to be $$f'(x,y,z)=(2x,4y,6z)=(2,-4,6) \text{ at } (1,-1,1)$$ and then compute $\nabla f(x,y,z) \bullet (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)$.

This gives me the tangent plane to be $$2(x-1)-4(y+1)+6(z-1).$$

I'm fairly sure that this is correct, I have no idea how to compute the normal line though.

Comment: Wouldn't any plane orthogonal to the tangent plane suffice?

Comment: your plane needs an  "= 0 "  at the end of it. Are you sure you are not being asked for the normal line through (1, -1, 1)? A normal plane at a point does not make much sense.

Comment: Oh good point, I mean normal line.

Comment: you have the vector $(2, -4, 6)$ that is normal at $(1, -1, 1).$ so the parametric equation is $x = 1+2t, y = -1-4t, z = a+6t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal line of a function $f(x,y,z)$, at some point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, is simply the line with normal vector $f^\prime$$(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ that passes through the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Then the equation of the normal line becomes: $r(t)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+t$·$f^\prime$$(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

In your case, $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,-1,1)$, and $f^\prime$$(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(2,-4,6).$

Hence, equation of the normal line is:

$$r(t)=(1,-1,1)+t(2,-4,6)$$ 
$$=(1+2t,-1-4t,1+6t)$$

The normal line in parametric equation form is then:

$$x(t)=1+2t$$
$$y(t)=-1-4t$$
$$z(t)=1+6t$$